# Add and remove parent class when input is focus or filled out

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I had made a javascript function to add and remove classes to the parent item when the input field within is on focus or filled out. This function somehow must have broke at some point when I updated Wordpress, but I don't know whats wrong with it.

This is my JavaScript:

```
$('.wpcf7-form-control').each(function() {
//console.log($(this));
$(this).on('focus', function() {
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('active');
});

$(this).on('blur', function() {
if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
$(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active');
}
});

if ($(this).val() != '') $(this).parent('.grid').addClass('active');

});
```

This is a HTML Sample of the form:

```
<div class="grid grid-3">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap firma">
<input type="text" name="firma" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="firma" aria-invalid="false">
</span>
<label for="firma">Firma</label>
</div>
```

Comment: what is happening and what is the expected output? Is there any errors on the dev tools log?

Comment: Are you trying to add the class to the `grid` container?

Comment: The div with the class grid should get the class active when the input is on focus or filled out. There are no errors in the console.